# Like statement in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, activerecord

I'm trying to run a simple like clause using the following code...

```
Message.where('to LIKE ?', '%hi')
```

My model class is as follows...

> class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> attr_accessor  :from, :error_messages, :use_background_job, :to
>   attr_accessible :status, :to, :from, :cc, :bcc, :subject, :body,
>   :error_messages, :use_background_job

I'm using activerecord and the activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter gem.  However I get the following error...

```
  ←[1m←[36mMessage Load (161.1ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "MESSAGES".* FROM "MESSAGES" WHERE (to LIKE 'hi')←[0m
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00936: missing expression: SELECT "MESSAGES".* FROM "MESSAGES"  WHERE (to LIKE 'hi')
        from stmt.c:230:in oci8lib_191.so
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:126:in `exec'
```

Is this an Oracle issue or is my syntax for the like clause incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "to" is a Oracle  Keyword.

Try this

```
Message.where('"to" LIKE ?', '%hi')
```

Oracle uses double quotes to escape keywords

Comment: This worked just needed to capitalize the "TO" because of the db column name.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Message.where('messages.to LIKE ?', '%hi')`. I think 'to' is a reserved keyword in sql.